# Node.js MongoDB on Ubuntu: no valid seed servers in list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, replication

I'm trying to connect to replica set from Ubuntu using this:

```
return when.promise(function(resolve,reject){
        new MongoClient().connect(url, {replSet: options }, function(err, db){
        console.dir(err)
        if (err)
            reject(err);

        resolve(db);
    });
});
```

Url looks like this:

`'mongodb://mongo1.mysite.com:36108,mongo2.mysite.com:36108,mongo3.mysite.com:36108/db_config?w=0'`

I'm connection to multiple databases and intermittently i see this error:

`{ name: 'MongoError', message: 'no valid seed servers in list' }`

And node.js crashes.

I'm kind of lost at this point.
And the main problem is that it works perfectly on MAC and i see this issue only on Ubuntu. I'm on the latest mongo driver for node.js

**UPDATE**

I took a look at the native driver source:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/replset.js.html

and found out tha error being triggered by this condition (line 987):
`state.initialConnectionServers == 0 && state.replState.state == CONNECTING)`

Still not sure why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the amount of file descriptors solved the issue.

On Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS default is 1024 which is not enough.

Comment: strange. swear that i had an actual file descriptor error instead of no valid seed servers but will look out for that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

the difference is that you don't have a replica set on your own single mac (osx?) laptop/desktop. its running in standalone mode. but do have or intend to have a replica set on those 3 servers.

here are some potential problems with the string provided.

1) 27017 is the default port for mongo so unless it was specifically changed to 36108 that is incorrect.

```
mongodb://mongo1.mysite.com:36108,mongo2.mysite.com:36108,mongo3.mysite.com:36108/db_config?w=0
```

try

```
mongodb://mongo1.mysite.com:27017,mongo2.mysite.com:27017,mongo3.mysite.com:27017/db_config?w=0
```

2) w=0 is unfamiliar to me, perhaps its the name of your replica set. usually the connection string for replica sets is as follows, where rs0 is the name of the replicaSet.

```
mongodb://mongo1.mysite.com:27017,mongo2.mysite.com:27017,mongo3.mysite.com:27017/replicaSet=rs0
```

3) its possible you have no replica set configured. check [rs.config](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/#rs.reconfig)

log into the server, mongo1.mysite.com

go into mongo shell using `mongo admin -u clusteradmin -p whateverpassword`

type

> rs.config()

if you dont see anything like the following then you have no replica set to connect to. here rs0 is the name of the replica set. yours MIGHT be called w???

```
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo1.mysite.com:36108"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongo2.mysite.com:36108"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo3.mysite.com:36108",
        }
    ]
}
```

4. if that config is missing you need to [add](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.add/) your 3 hosts into the replica set config.

rs.add("mongo1.mysite.com:36108") // or the default port with "mongo1.mysite.com:27017"
rs.add("mongo2.mysite.com:36108")
rs.add("mongo3.mysite.com:36108")

But better than anything is brush up o replica sets including this [doc to convert a standalone to a replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)

The given /db_config string looks like a rs.config() equivalent command but done by http and expects a list of servers to add to a replica set. but frankly you cannot connect to a replica set to configure it? so that seems odd. you can connect to the primary so try

```
mongodb://mongo1.mysite.com:36108/db_config?w=mongo1.mysite.com:36108,mongo2.mysite.com:36108,mongo3.mysite.com:36108
```

Comment: Thank you for very long reply: 1. On my Mac i'm using remote replica set and it works. On Ubuntu it does not. 2. I have set ports on members as 36108 explicitly. 3. w=0 disables safe writes, please refer to MonbgoClient docs for more info. 4. Replica set is configured and functional members are "healthy" 5. I dont not need to add anything to my replica set and the url you provided is incorrect

Comment: db_config -> name of the database

Comment: Can you try connecting to the replica set from the mongo shell on the Ubuntu machine? Try to use the same connection string adapted for `mongo`.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the solutions given by [rinchnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27275387/4018748) and [Gabe rainbow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27208092/4018748). And if the problem still persists then please update the modules - "mongodb" to version 2.2.27+ and "mongoose" to version 4.9.1+ .

Comment: Great, upgrading mogoose to version 4.9.1 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had this error from an EC2 instance pointing to Mongodb Atlas.

This issue was resolved when we added our EC2 ip to Mongodb Atlas' ip whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the connection worked with updating the "mongoose" and "mongodb to the new version.
The dbURI formats used for different versions are different. Have a look at that as well.